# Android Studio 3.1 - kotlin plugin does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.1

I updated my AS from 3.0 to 3.1. After fixing several issues that showed up with the update, I am stuck at making Kotlin work.

Kotlin code compiles and runs, although I can't edit kotlin files. Kotlin keywords are not recognised by the editor, using kotlin code from java classes appear red and in general I can't really do anything with kotlin.

I use:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    ...
    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

kotlin plugin: `1.2.41-release-Studio3.1-1` 
and `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version`

Comment: set `gradle:3.1.2`

Comment: Tried that, same results.

Comment: do you have:

    dependencies{
         implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    }

in your project gradle

Comment: @Asdf have you solved this ?

Comment: look at this question [Kotlin not working on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180559/kotlin-not-working-on-android-studio)