# kotlin plugin doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I import kotlin and enabled kotlin plugin.I found that they doesn't work as well.Some description is like [Android Studio 3.1 - kotlin plugin does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098853/android-studio-3-1-kotlin-plugin-does-not-work)
.

I not only can't new any kotlin file、class .etc but also cant't use kotlin grammar in java file.When I tried to use 「Convert Java File To Kotlin File」 function.It's successd.But When I close this file and reopen this file.This file is blank.

All my kotlin configuration as follows.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    ...
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
...
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And some phenomenon like I can't modify kotlin file When I use 「Convert Java File To Kotlin File」 function.Some pictures as follows.

[My kotlin file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ZDw.png)

When I tried to new kotlin file,I meet some troubles:

[Can not create File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vZ5w.png)

[My Kotlin Code Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSfkk.png)

Because I don't have enough repupation to submit pictures,so I put them as a link. Could someone can help me?Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm first time for ask questions on stackoverflow.I'm sorry for my Inconsiderate and I make some edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this question.It's because that *.kt extension is not associated with the Kotlin Files.But associated with the Java Class Files.Check those configurations : Settings | Editor | File Types.For more information.See this question [Kotlin not working on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180559/kotlin-not-working-on-android-studio)